# Not able to click a sign in button using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is what inspect element option in `chrome` has found.

```
<input class="buttonstylenormal margin-top5" type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="return isFirstClick()">
```

It is not having `ID` in it, which would have made my work easier. All I have now is `class`, `value` and `type`. With these I am not able to click the button `Sign In`.

Please help me with the right code to click this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below xpath.

**Explanation:** Use `value` attribute of `input` tag.

```
 //input[@value='Sign In']
```

OR

**Explanation:** Use `class` and `value` attribute of `input` tag.

```
//input[@class='buttonstylenormal margin-top5'][@value='Sign In']
```

OR

**Explanation:** Use `class` and `type` attribute of `input` tag.

```
//input[@class='buttonstylenormal margin-top5'][@type='submit']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! first explanation works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XPath`, as @jainish said, or try to use `CssSelector`, that uses the same syntax that CSS has to apply styles.

To find it using `CssSelector`, you can use a few variations:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']"))
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.buttonstylenormal.margin-top5"))
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.buttonstylenormal.margin-top5[type='submit']"))
```

`CssSelector` may help you even in other elements you'd like to find that do not have an ID.

Hope it's somehow helpful.